# JavaScript / Save context of varaible inside async function

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in JavaScript:

```
for (var i = 0; i< uuids.length; i++){
     var attr = uuids[i]
     var uuid = attr["uuid"];
     console.log("uuid is: " + uuid)
     multiClient.hget(var1, var2, function(err, res1){
          console.log("uuid INSIDE hget is: " + uuid)
      }
}
```

`hget` is an async method. Here are the prints of this function:

```
"uuid is: 1"
"uuid is: 2"
"uuid INSIDE hget is: 2"
"uuid INSIDE hget is: 2"
```

I wish to save the context of the uuid inside the hget function, so I will get:

```
"uuid is: 1"
"uuid is: 2"
"uuid INSIDE hget is: 1" (where all the context before the loop has saved for this uuid)
"uuid INSIDE hget is: 2" (where all the context before the loop has saved for this uuid)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code

```
multiClient.hget(var1, var2, function(err, res1){
   console.log("uuid INSIDE hget is: " + uuid)
}
```

`uuid` value will be the value when async operation is completed.

You can solve this using anonymous function  executing and copy the value of `uuid` to some other variable say `uuid_temp` and use that value as shown below.

```
(function() {
   var uuid_temp = uuid;
   multiClient.hget(var1, var2, function(err, res1){
      console.log("uuid INSIDE hget is: " + uuid_temp); //note uuid_temp here
   }
}());
```